# .Index method in Visual Basic "Method or data member cannot found"

Tags: vba

[when i want to log in, there will be a msg box stating "Method or data member not found" and when i click ok, it highlight the .Index
I'm trying to connect the vb and the ms access database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq4ud.png)

Hi, Please help

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. Apparently you are trying to access a table, or perhaps a data row which doesn't exist. In many cases this is caused by a variable that unexpectedly evaluates to zero. The only way to resolve this problem is to look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Recordsets support **Index** and **Seek**.  Are you sure that you opened the Recordset with the proper parameters?

Follow this example from [Seek Method and Index Property Example (VB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/seek-method-and-index-property-example-vb).  Make sure that you are using the same parameters to Open the Recordset.

```
 rstEmployees.Open strSQLEmployees, strCnxn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly, adCmdTableDirect
```

Then use this Snippet to see if **Index** and **Seek** are supported:

```
' Does this provider support Seek and Index?  
If rs1.Supports(adIndex) And rs1.Supports(adSeek) Then  
    MsgBox "Success: Seek and Index are Supported"
Else
   MsgBox "Failure:  Seek and Index are not Supported"
End If
```